# Z-index with position relative and sticky doesn;t work

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I need to add new functionality to projekt. On top I have menu with z-index:999 (position:relative) ( I ty to reduce z-index but component is too extensive.
Lower I have my component and inside i have button that opens a modal.
And here's the problem
I have modal on sticky position (top, right, bottom, left - 0).I want this to cover the entire page.(z-index:99999)
But unfortunately the menu component is upper.
Do you have any idea how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed this. I needed to extract the component with the modal from the parent element.

Comment: @Joanna: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mind offering a bit more explanation about _how_ you accomplished this? It might be useful to include some code. That will help future readers with similar issues figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any overflow: hiddens? if so try removing those lines.

Comment: no, i only need to change order. Now i have:
<menu></menu>
<componentModal></componentModal>
<component></component>
before i have:
<menu></menu>
<component>
     <componentModal></componentModal>
</component>